# Decrypt XML with Private Key c#

Tags: c#, xml, encryption

Decrypt XML with Private Key c#

I got this XML that I needs to decrypt. The xml is encrypted with a public Key, which the sender got from my p12 certificate, which is in my certificate store. It’s based on the W3c’s XML Encryption Syntax and Processing standard.

How do I decrypt this I use C# 4.5. I have looked in the msdn and tried other examples with no luck.
Do I have to extract the private key from the certificate? Below the XML there is an example in Java that should Work, but I can't how the got the private key.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?> 
<urn:PersonSamtykkeOpret_O xmlns:urn="urn:oio:skat:hentselv:ws:1.0.1">
<xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content">
  <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" /> 
 <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<xenc:EncryptedKey>
  <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" /> 
<xenc:CipherData>
  <xenc:CipherValue>cdvDSYkcUTu59nEqHg9GhMxS6yGK7ZLVdghluipkUT7PxwwJ2+N9HZcIg4XI26y5Q0mzNg6IixEB….. xenc:CipherValue> 
  </xenc:CipherData>
  </xenc:EncryptedKey>
  </ds:KeyInfo>
<xenc:CipherData>
  <xenc:CipherValue>D/aMUyUAzuaEJSLfiOLEEOshXoUQ5yNRUxdVFq6Jlg1+p6emUephz86THWXiy00EC+zgD9olqsm6…. </xenc:CipherValue> 
  </xenc:CipherData>
  </xenc:EncryptedData>
  </urn:PersonSamtykkeOpret_O>
```

This is an example that works in Java:

```
public void decryptXMLDocument(Document xmlDocToDecrypt, 
PrivateKey decryptionPrivateKey) throws Exception { 
try { 
// Find Encryption Element i XML Document 
Element _encryptedDataElement = 
(Element) xmlDocToDecrypt.getElementsByTagNameNS( 
EncryptionConstants.EncryptionSpecNS, EncryptionConstants._TAG_ENCRYPTEDDATA).item(0); 
System.out.print("EcryptedData element found in Document"); 
// Create XMLCipher to do the decryption 
XMLCipher _xmlCipher = XMLCipher.getInstance(); 
_xmlCipher.init(XMLCipher.DECRYPT_MODE, null); 
_xmlCipher.setKEK(decryptionPrivateKey); 
System.out.print("XMLChiper initeret"); 
/* 
* The following doFinal call replaces the encrypted data with 
* decrypted contents in the document. 
*/ 
_xmlCipher.doFinal(xmlDocToDecrypt, _encryptedDataElement); 
System.out.print("Document decrypted"); 

} catch (Exception e) { 
System.out.print("Failed to decrypt document :: " + e); 
throw new Exception("Failed to decrypt document"); 
} 
}
```

Comment: I found the solution. The symmetric key was encrypted with my private key. so after decrtypting the symmetric key I could decrypt the rest of the xml